# При увеличении блока, некоторый контент "съезжает"

Tags: html, css

На странице находятся карточки героев. Горизонтально расположено 4 карточки.
Добавил для карточек свойство, при наведении на них, увеличиваться.

```
//Карточка Героя
.hero__main__card {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

//Увеличение при наведении
.hero__main__card:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    transform:scale(1.1);
    z-index: .1;
    border: 2px solid green;
    box-shadow: 15px 3px 25px gray, -1em 0 .4em skyblue;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

Всё круто работает, но есть одно НО! При увеличении карточки, карточка под увеличенной начинает съезжать вправо, остальные переносятся ещё ниже. Такое происходит с первыми 3-мя карточками. При наведении на 4-ую (последнюю в линни), карточка под ней остаётся на месте, но немного опускается ниже (вместе с остальными перед ней).
Можно ли это как-то исправить?
Код самой карточки:

```
<h1 class="hogo1 mt-3 mb-2">Heroes</h1>
            @can('view', auth()->user())
                <div class="hogo1 mb-3">
                    <a href="{{ route('hero.create') }}" class="btn btn-outline-info">Создать карточку героя</a>
                </div>
            @endcan
            @foreach($heroes as $hero)
                <a href="{{ route('hero.show', $hero->id) }}" class="card hero__main__card mb-4">
                    <div class="border-success" style="width: 17rem;">
                        <h4>
                            <div class="card-header bg-transparent border-success hogo1">{{ $hero->name }}</div>
                        </h4>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <img class="image__hero mb-1 card-img-top" src="{{ asset('storage/images/hero/' . $hero->image) }}" alt="img"
                                 style="width: 250px; height: 200px">
                            <h5 class="card-title">О персонаже:<br>
                                <li class="li__marker__hero">{{ Illuminate\Support\Str::limit($hero->about, 50) }}</li>
                            </h5> <!--limit(текст, ограничение) -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer bg-transparent border-success text-info">
                            <h6>Способности: <br>
                                <li class="li__marker__ability">{{ $hero->ability->ability }}</li>
                            </h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer bg-transparent border-success text-warning">
                            <h6>Особых навыков:
                                {{ $hero->skills->count() }}
                            </h6>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

Можете зафиксировать размер по ширине для данных карточек, добавить ещё один слой (`div` оббертку) в середину каждой карточки и задавать эффект масштабированию уже этому слою. Корректнее объяснить не получиться, поскольку вы не предоставили нормальную `СSS\HTML` структуру. * а та что предоставлена с точки зрения `seo` некорректна.